# Adding XYErrorRenderer to ScatterChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to add the error bars over the datapoints in a scatter plot using [`XYErrorRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYErrorRenderer.html). The dataset used is `XYDataset`. The code I have used for it is:

```
XYErrorRenderer rendererPoints = new XYErrorRenderer();
rendererPoints.setShapesVisible(true);
rendererPoints.setDrawXError(false);
rendererPoints.setDrawYError(true);
rendererPoints.setCapLength(new Double(0.2));

rendererPoints.setShapesFilled(true);
rendererPoints.setLinesVisible(false);
```

I want to add the error bars vertically, but it is not working for me. Please help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I have solved the query with the combination of StatasticalCatagoryDataset,  StatisticalLineandShapeRenderer... as it provded me the deviation to be included in the datapoints..

Answer (score 1):

[`XYErrorRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYErrorRenderer.html) "expects an [`IntervalXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/IntervalXYDataset.html), otherwise it reverts to the behaviour of the super class." This probably explains why `XYDataset` isn't working. [`XYIntervalSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYIntervalSeries.html) looks like it has room to `add()` both intervals for each point.